# After Spring Boot 2.3.0 migration no more TransactionTemplate available

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have a very simple Spring Boot application with only one dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-activemq</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

After migrating the application to 2.3.0 it no longer starts. The error is:

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Parameter 1 of constructor in com.bookstore.shipping.service.ShippingService required a bean of type 'org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate' that could not be found.

The following candidates were found but could not be injected:
    - Bean method 'transactionTemplate' in 'TransactionAutoConfiguration.TransactionTemplateConfiguration' not loaded because @ConditionalOnSingleCandidate (types: org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager; SearchStrategy: all) did not find any beans


Action:

Consider revisiting the entries above or defining a bean of type 'org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate' in your configuration.
```

How do I have to configure the TransactionTemplate in Spring 2.3.0? In previous versions this worked out of the box.